# My code isn't moving on to the next step even though there are no errors Node JS

Tags: node.js

I've been experimenting with Node JS recently and for some reason, my code does not continue onto the next step even though it is supposed to.

Here is my code:

```
const request = require('request');
var jssoup = require('jssoup').default;
const {Harvester} = require('captcha-manager');

const harvester = new Harvester();
async function run(){
//                                               hostname      sitekey
    global.response = await harvester.getResponse('adidas.com', '6LdC0iQUAAAAAOYmRv34KSLDe-7DmQrUSYJH8eB_');
    console.log(response);
}

async function normalCheckout(size, style){
    console.log('started');


    if (size == 14.5){
        var shoesize = style + '_740';
    }

    if (size == 15){
        var shoesize = style + '_750';
    }

    if (size == 15.5){
        var shoesize = style + '_760';
    }

    if (size == 16){
        var shoesize = style + '_770'
    }
    console.log(shoesize);
    var options = {
        url: 'https://www.adidas.com/us/optik_literally_takes_stock/' + style +'.html',
        headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
            },
        form: {
            "product_id":style,
            "quantity":1,
            "product_variation_sku":shoesize,
            "productId":shoesize,
            "size":str(size),
            "displaySize":str(size),
            "captchaResponse":response
        },
    };
    console.log('step finished');
    run();
}

normalCheckout(16, 'BD7730')
```

NOTE: The dictionary for `form` is formatted correctly in my actual code, for some reason I cannot format it correctly here.

When I run it, `started` is logged and the variable `shoesize` is logged but `step finished` is not logged, even though it is supposed to be.  Why is this happening and how can I fix this?  Additionally, is there any way for me to condense all of my `if` statements?

Comment: Dude, couple things: 1- You should use a switch for all these size == 5, 6, etc. 2- Remove most of them when posting here, to get the point of what your code is doing,  3 of them is fine.

Comment: Can you explain your code? Aside from str(size) that should be throwing an error, why are you declaring options if you never use it? Why are you using a global variable that will be used before it is created?

Comment: @iagowp I definitely should've included this in my code before posting (sorry about that by the way) options is declared because I'm going to be sending a post request to adidas with the parameters defined in options and I ended up fixing the whole response variable issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment to the `options` variable gets stuck, because it assigns `response` as a value to one of its elements, but that variable doesn’t exist yet (it is defined only later, by the `run()` function).

Why this doesn’t throw an error is unclear.

Comment: That shouldn't throw an error - `response` is just undefined and the value will be assigned as such.

Comment: In Node v8 I get an error when I try to set a variable equal to a nonexistent one: `ReferenceError: x is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your shoe size mapping - I would use an object to map it:

```
const shoeSizeMap = {
 4:'_730', 
 4.5: '_540', 
 //etc
}

const shoesize = style + shoeSizeMap[size];
```

Re why it isn't continuing - are you sure you aren't getting an error?

For example, I can't see a `str` method being defined anywhere.

Comment: No errors but I think that might be why, I'll try it using string(size) now.  I guess I'm too used to Python with the str().